# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') - Shopify, Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, shopify

I'm using Shopify that is my original theme under development with vuejs. And I am trying to change variant by select form.
but when change the variant by select form, there is the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')".

I get this error.

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Shopify.Product.getVariantById (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.selectVariant (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.selectVariantFromDropdown (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.initDropdown (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at new Shopify.OptionSelectors (option_selection-fe6b72c2bbdd3369ac0bfefe8648e3c889efca213baefd4cfb0dd9363563831f.js:1)
    at wn.changeVariants (product.js?a058:77)
    at He (VM10730 vue.min.js:599)
    at HTMLSelectElement.n (VM10730 vue.min.js:703)
    at HTMLSelectElement.Yr.o._wrapper (VM10730 vue.min.js:2405)
```

and my source code.

```html
# product-template.liquid

<div id="product">
<select id="product-select" name="id"
                    ref="productSelect" v-on:change="changeVariants">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}
      <option data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}"
              {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
        {{ variant.title }}
      </option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```

```js
# main.js

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.min';
import axios from 'axios';

new Vue({

  delimiters: ['${', '}'],

  data() {
    return {

      data: '',
      productSelect: '',
      productQuantity: 1,
      productData: {},

    };
  },

  created() {
    axios
      .get(`${window.location.href}.js`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.data = res.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },

  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },

  methods: {

    init() {
      this.productSelect = this.$refs.productSelect;

      this.productData = {
        id: this.productSelect.value,
        quantity: this.productQuantity,
      };
    },

    changeVariants() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-new,no-undef
      new Shopify.OptionSelectors('product-select', {
        product: this.data,
        onVariantSelected: this.selectCallback,
        enableHistoryState: true,
      });
    },

    changeQuantity() {
      this.productData.quantity = this.productQuantity;
    },

    addToCart(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      axios
        .post('/cart/add.js', this.productData)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('ok.');
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('error.');
        });
    },

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    selectCallback(variant, selector) {
      this.productData.id = variant.id;
    },

  },

}).$mount('#product');
```

I'm not good at English.
If you want more information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: In changeVariants you assign this.data to products - could it be that this.data is undefined there, i.e. you've no data from your get?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is my mistake...

```.get(`${window.location.href}.js`)```

↓
```
const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
const params = currentUrl.searchParams;
params.delete('variant');
const productUrl = currentUrl.href;
```